# Rasa Fall back policy for faq chatbot

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am working on Rasa Faq chatbot using retrieval actions. For there I want to implement fall back policy , but I implemented in many ways suggested on net but fallback policy is not working.
The reason I found for that is I have faq intent specified in NLU.md file and responses written in responses.md for the faq.
Every time i give out of scope question it catches the faq intent and gives first answer in that faq responses.md but not default answer I mentioned in domain file.

Can anybody suggest any method in which fallback can work specifically in FAQ chatbot for Rasa

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking two questions:

To your first, if you're using response selector, fallback will kick in as normal if confidence is below the threshold you set. Giving an "out of scope" question will not necessarily simulate this.

Secondly, the responses in `responses.md` are **always** the ones referred to by the response selector; those you set in the domain are not relevant to response selector in Rasa 1.x